# Estimate offset of Scrollview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a Tableview(B) inside a scrollview(A). I set disable scrollview(A) after specific content offset.

When I Scroll a Scrollview(A) with some more power, it will stop after condition is satisfied.
But I want to know how much can Scrollview content offset if I will not set the Condition for stop it. So, I can set content offset of Tableview(B) as per offset of ScrollView(A).

**How to do this?**

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView{
    CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){.origin = self.scrollview.contentOffset, .size = self.scrollview.bounds.size};
        CGPoint visiblePoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), visibleRect.origin.y);
NSLog(@"offset: %f",visiblePoint.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:

Set the scroll view delegate for ScrollView(a)  and then use targetContentOffset to modify your TableView(b)

specifically: scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:  of the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol.